# Universal Deep Links with Mandrill sub domain

Tags: ios, subdomain, mandrill, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I have Universal Deep Links working for my iOS app, Neighbourly (associated with neighbourly.co.nz)

We send out emails to our users and use Mandrill to track clicks. The email links go to a subdomain clicks.neighbourly.co.nz/path which points to mandrillapp.com/path and the links redirect to neighbourly.co.nz/newpath

Ive added applinks:clicks.neighbourly.co.nz to the apps associated domains.

My apple-app-site-association file's paths is a wildcard: ["*"]

But, while links to neighbourly.co.nz launch the app correctly, links to clicks.neighbourly.co.nz launch in Safari. What am I missing?

I can't find any info online about setting up subdomains for deep links

Does my apple-app-site-association file need to be hosted at mandrillapp.com?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I work with mandrill and it seems to be breaking my universal links

Comment: I believe that the apple-app-site-association file would need to be hosted at mandrillapp.com. I emailed Mandrill directly but they wouldn't let me put it there temporarily to test it. They indicated that they'd probably look into the situation in the future but, at present to have deep linking we'd have to stop using Mandrill.

Comment: We'd rather have deep linking over Mandrill so will stop using them and just rely on Google Analytics

Comment: Cool, thanks for the update!

Answer (score 6):

Mandrill's tracking may also be messing with the universal link.

I got around this by disabling mandrill tracking for my branch.io links

`mc:disable-tracking` is the key

In my template:

```
<a href="http://mybranchsubdomomain.mydomain.com/something" mc:disable-tracking>Disabled Mandrill URL</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

We solved this at the DNS (kinda) level using [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com) (an amazing service I'd recommend using anyway).

Set up Mandrill to use a custom domain for click tracking using Cloudflare as the DNS provider. In the screenshots below for example it is track.yourdomain.com set up in Mandrill and Cloudflare.

Mandrill tracking domain:
[image: mandrill settings]

Cloudflare DNS:
[image: cloudflare dns]

Then in Cloudflare use their "Page Rules" feature to create a redirect to the `apple-app-site-association` file you have hosted on your actual website (assuming it has the rules that will work on both domains, otherwise you can probably redirect to another file, I didn't test this)

Cloudflare page rules:
[image: cloudflare page rules]

I also added a cache bypass rule because you want all requests to the track.yourdomain.com to reach your origin server and not get cached by an edge server.

Comment: Hello, so if i get correctly there is a cname pointing to mandrill domain and a page rule to redirect. Which one works when there is a request? Will the request hit mandrill tracker and respond the apple-app-association file? Best

Comment: Sorry but i just gıt it :) All urls are automatically redirected to mandrill except the apple app association file. Thanks for solution :)

Comment: One question though; If app is installed and assuming that association file worked well with custom tracking domain. Will IOS pass the link with custom tracking subdomain to the app without hitting the url in the background? If not so to make mandrill still track the link did you make curl request in the app when the link is received? And if you did that did you get the original link or redirect result link? Best

Answer (score 1):

First of all you don't need to host `apple-app-site-association` file at mandrillapp.com.

Second thing  you need to add `applinks:neighbourly.co.nz` to the apps associated domains.

Because I just checked, if I'm requesting to your server for `apple-app-site-association` with URL https://clicks.neighbourly.co.nz/apple-app-site-association then your server return 404 file not found.

Then, I found and downloaded your `apple-app-site-association` from url https://www.neighbourly.co.nz/apple-app-site-association and I checked **you are using the old format**. Here your current association file

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": {
      "2E23KCX8SU.nz.co.neighbourly.ios": {
        "paths":[ "*", "/" ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

replace your old `apple-app-site-association` file with this new format

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "2E23KCX8SU.nz.co.neighbourly.ios",
        "paths":[ "*", "/"  ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

After update `apple-app-site-association` file test it with [Apple Validation Tool](https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool/)

---

#### App Search API Validation Tool Result

**For -> https://clicks.neighbourly.co.nz/apple-app-site-association**
[image]

---

**For -> https://neighbourly.co.nz/apple-app-site-association**
[image]

Comment: https://clicks.neighbourly.co.nz/apple-app-site-association isn't my server, it points directly to mandrillapp.com which is why theres no apple-app-site-association file there.

Comment: I don't see how links to clicks.neighbourly.co.nz can launch my app when clicks.neighbourly.co.nz isn't my server and my apple-app-site-association file can't be hosted there - can you explain?

Comment: Thanks for your answer btw!

Comment: The json file can't be hosted at mandrill, per mandrill: "iOS Deep Links don't allow for integration with Mandrill's current click-tracking mechanisms. At this time, we're not able to host any custom JSON files at our domain, so any behavior to launch an app directly would need to be handled directly by your own domain. Unfortunately, this means that our click-tracking (via redirect) system won't report this activity."