# iOS 9 Deep-linking with third party Mandrill/MailChimp

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, mandrill, deep-linking

We implemented iOS9 Universal Deep-linking in our app and it is working fine with our current domain. Now we are using Mandrill platform to send email to our subscribers that redirect to our actual URL and now the mandrill URL open in Safari and redirect to our actual URL but our app does not open.

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Hey, I have the same problem as you, here they say that it is not possible for the moment :/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33882647/universal-deep-links-with-mandrill-sub-domain

Comment: Thanks @PaulSlm for update.

Comment: Please provide more details like what your domain name and how you implementing etc

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @user1218464, still I did not find any solution for this issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33882647/universal-deep-links-with-mandrill-sub-domain/40538179#40538179

Answer (score 1):

I got around this by disabling mandrill tracking for my branch links

`mc:disable-tracking` is the key

In my template:

```
<a href="http://branch.io/something" mc:disable-tracking>Disabled Mandrill URL</a>
```